# Dark Gray background on text - Visual Studio

Tags: text, colors, editor

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rilgm.png)

The dark grey part behind every word, not the light grey selection boxes.

Does anybody have any idea what setting can actually get rid of it?  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Just put background color for all user-related items to automatic:

[image: Like this!]